I am trying to generate Api using openApi. Problem is when i enter the url in postman it gives me html instead of json file
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.14</version>
</dependency>

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.OpenAPIDefinition;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.info.Info;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;


@SpringBootApplication
@OpenAPIDefinition(
        info = @Info(
                title="to-do-list",
                version = "1.0",
                description = "first to do list"
        )
)

@Import(PokemonConfig.class)
public class PokemonApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PokemonApplication.class, args);
    }

}


I am using the version 1.6.14 also tried with other version 2.5.0 but could not solve it
I have controller and service class which do not have error. I am trying to generate yaml file.

Which Accept header have you set in your Postman request? Is it set to application/json ?

Your question is not exactly clear to me. What exactly you're expecting with your code?

i am trying to get OpenApi using restcontroller?I have controller , service and all working but want to genrate OpenApi? can you help me
